# Connect to mysql with sqlalchemy and query

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I have a MySQL database with stock market quotes. I'm trying to create a python script to connect to the database and query it. Here is my python script...

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:password@localhost:8889/database_name'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Stocks(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'stocks'
    stock_id = db.Column('stock_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    adj_close = db.Column('adj_close', db.Float)
    close = db.Column('close', db.Float)
    date = db.Column('date', db.Date)
    high = db.Column('high', db.Float)
    low = db.Column('low', db.Float)
    open = db.Column('open', db.Float)
    symbol = db.Column('symbol', db.String(10))
    volume = db.Column('volume ', db.Float)
```

I'm trying to query the data base utilizing the python console with the following commands...

```
>>>from file.py import Stocks
>>>data = Stocks.query.all()
```

And I get the following error...

```
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I'm running python 2.7.12

If I run this code with python 3.5.2 I get the following error...

```
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

If I try to install `MySQLdb` I get the following...

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for MySQLdb
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a "mysql://..." connection string, SQLAlchemy will use the MySQL-python to connect by default, so you need to install that package using pip.

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Alternatively, you can use another library to connect, such as PyMySQL (MySQL-python is no longer actively developed).  Just change your connection string:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost:8889/database_name'
```

To install PyMySQL:

```
pip install PyMySQL
```